PVC coupling Leak
How do I fix this leak where there is no room to cut the pipe between the 45 elbow and T? I have circled the joint where it is leaking and also included another picture from another angle to show the whole configuration. It is slow leak, just dripping but has to be fixed.


Looks like an inside coupling.  There is enough room between the two pipes to cut.  There are coupling saving cutters/grinders that might remove the glued coupling from the joint.

Could I just cut between the two pipes and then use a rubber coupling over the joint (the 45 and the T)?

Possible, but the clamps have to be on the straight/smooth sections of the pipes to seal tight.

@crip659 the ridges on the bells could be sanded/filed flat.  That might make it smooth enough to use a Fernco or equivalent.

So I ended up cutting the pipes about an inch from the joint where is was leaking (away from the wall side) then used a heat gun to remove the pipe from the connector. This took a some time and effort. I had to sand down the inside of the connector with fine sandpaper. Then just rebuilt everything with new pipe and connectors. No leaks after 2 days.
